# Assigning values in functions called $interval

Tags: angularjs

I'm having difficulty understanding how value assignments are handled within functions called by $interval.

Given the following code:

```
this.value = null;
this.setSelection = function() {
    this.value = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
};
this.isSelected = function(item) {
    if(this.value === item) {
        return "selected";
    }
};
```

If I call the setSelection in this manner `$interval(this.setSelection, 2000);` the function is called as on the defined interval, but the scope of the assigned value seems to be such that the actual `this.value` is not altered and when the digest calls `isSelected`, the value is still `null`.

However, if I call the function directly (such as this incorrect form) `$interval(this.setSelection(), 2000);` the value is correctly updated and when digest runs `isSelected` it recognizes the new value. Obviously, the interval does not run again because `$interval` had expected a function reference.

I had also tried wrapping the function call in an anonymous function, but this resulted in an error stating the function was undefined.

So my question is, why when my function is called correctly by $interval, I get this unexpected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` depends on context. When calling `$interval(this.setSelection, 2000)`, you are losing the context of `this`. The method is called just as a function. When `this.value = ...` is being executed, `this` is something completely different than what you expect (probably the containing function).

One way to fix this is a simple workaround:

```
this.value = null;
var self = this;
this.setSelection = function() {
    self.value = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
};
```

Another solution is to bind the function to `this`:

```
$interval(this.setSelection.bind(this), 2000)
```

Comment: Interesting. I had assumed that <code>this</code> should be in context as $interval is an angular function, and it was used within the controller calling a function using $this. Will 'this' only be in context if the function call originates from the digest or otherwise explicitly bind it?

Comment: @msg45f This has nothing to do with angular or digests. This is a javascript thing. `this` refers to the enclosing scope and when you pass a method where a function is expected, the context of the object is lost and you get an independent function where `this` means something different.

Comment: I see. The source of my confusion was that in a separate controller, a method called by `ng-click` had `this` in context, and when it wasn't when called by `$interval` I wasn't sure what had gone wrong.